# Metro style app (Elysium) build on windows 8 not work on windows 7

Tags: wpf, microsoft-metro

I build some metro style apps with 1 form. My os - Windows 8, and I use Visual studio 2010.
If I create metro style apps using MahApps.Metro - everything fine - they run on windows 7.
But if I use Elysium.theme - my apps doesn't run on windows 7.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

P.s. The sample from http://elysium.codeplex.com/ work fine both win 7 and win 8.

Comment: Elysium should works fine on both Win 7 and Win 8. What error you ran into when you run Elysium project on Win 8?

Answer (score 0):

Elysium has both uses 4.0 and 4.5 of .Net, Please find which you have added as reference in your project. Better use 4.0, so that it can run on both OS.